# How to let two EditTexts scroll synchronous

Tags: android, android-edittext, synchronous

I want to put two EditText control in a LinerLayout. And put them one left and another right.

Now I want to realize a function like this: when the EditText context in right scroll up and down, the edittext content in left also scroll synchronous.

How to do this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Put this `LinearLayout` with two `EditText`s inside a `ScrollView`.
2. `EditText` inherits after `View`, which has methods `scrollTo()` and `onScrollChanged()`. Override `onScrollChanged()` for first `EditText`, in which you you will call `scrollTo()` of the second `EditText`.